# Windows Media Center Missing?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-media-center

I'm running Windows Vista SP2 64-bit, but it was SP1 when I bought the laptop. It came with Windows Media Center, but I originally found no use for it, so I deleted the shortcut.

Now I DO want to use it, and I can't find it anywhere. However, when I insert a DVD, the option to play it with Windows Media Center will appear, and it will launch Windows Media Center, so I must still have it on my system somewhere.

My question is, where? Is there an easy way to just run the program using the Run window?

Answer (score 3):

Media center is located at :

> %windir%\ehome\ehshell.exe

Create a new shortcut to that and it should work fine... You can then move it to the start menu or wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the shortcut with:

Location: %SystemRoot%\ehome\ehshell.exe
Name: Windows Media Center

When the shortcut is finished, in its Properties you can add

Start in: %SystemRoot%\ehome